# Doctrine returning a Undefined variable: metadata Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-7.2

I'm attempting to use Doctrine to generate entities for use with a new application. I have used Doctrine before, and have never had this issue, and I can't seem to find an answer for why this is happening anywhere online.
I am currently running this on Ubuntu 17.10 with PHP-7.2 and Doctrine version `doctrine/orm: ^2.5`.

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database php models/mapping
```

Then after the mapping file is made, it looks like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;

$metadata->setInheritanceType(ClassMetadataInfo::INHERITANCE_TYPE_NONE);
$metadata->setPrimaryTable(array(
   'name' => 'subscriptions',
  ));
$metadata->setChangeTrackingPolicy(ClassMetadataInfo::CHANGETRACKING_DEFERRED_IMPLICIT);
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'id',
   'columnName' => 'id',
   'type' => 'integer',
   'nullable' => false,
   'options' => 
   array(
   'unsigned' => false,
   ),
   'id' => true,
  ));
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'site',
   'columnName' => 'site',
   'type' => 'string',
   'nullable' => false,
   'length' => 25,
   'options' => 
   array(
   'fixed' => false,
   ),
  ));
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'endpoint',
   'columnName' => 'endpoint',
   'type' => 'string',
   'nullable' => false,
   'length' => 45,
   'options' => 
   array(
   'fixed' => false,
   ),
  ));
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'userpublickey',
   'columnName' => 'userPublicKey',
   'type' => 'string',
   'nullable' => false,
   'length' => 255,
   'options' => 
   array(
   'fixed' => false,
   ),
  ));
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'userauthtoken',
   'columnName' => 'userAuthToken',
   'type' => 'string',
   'nullable' => false,
   'length' => 255,
   'options' => 
   array(
   'fixed' => false,
   ),
  ));
$metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadataInfo::GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY);
```

Then I attempt to run this command:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=true models/entities
```

And I am presented with an error stating that:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: metadata
```

Does anyone know why Doctrine would be generating a mapping that has an undefined variable, and what I would do to fix it?